# How to sort an array using only the first 5 characters of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sorting

So, say I have an array of strings such as:
["74712 Don", "48342 Cindy", "50912 Nick"]
and I want to sort them by the number in front of the name. How would I sort by only the first 5 characters of each element (while also evaluating them as numbers)? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you wish to sort by the leading digits of the strings, you can do the following:

```
["74712 Don", "48342 Cindy", "50912 Nick"].sort_by(&:to_i)
  #=> ["48342 Cindy", "50912 Nick", "74712 Don"]
```

This works because [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) ignores "extraneous characters past the end of a valid number".

If some elements of the array may have more than five leading digits, but only the first five are to be considered, one would use

```
 ["74712 Don", "48342 Cindy", "209124  Nick"].sort_by {  |s|
   s[0,5].to_i }
  #=> ["209124  Nick", "48342 Cindy", "74712 Don"]
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `\A`. And if you don't need to save the string by removing any non-digit characters at the beginning, then you can simply do `s[0, 5].to_i`.

Comment: @sawa True but it doesn't hurt and (IMO) helps express the intent of the code.

Comment: There's also `numeric_prefix = ->(s) { s[/\A\d{,5}/].to_i }` and then `array.sort_by(&numeric_prefix)`. I find that attaching names to little bits of logic makes things easier to read six months down the road. Sure, it will be a tiny bit slower but rarely enough to matter.

Comment: @sawa, thanks. I made both changes you suggested. (Readers: I formerly had `s[/\A\d{,5}/].to_i`, which explains μ's comment.)